# when assigning variable values by function: typescript error: variable is used before being assigned [2454]

Tags: typescript, next.js

so im building a store using nextJS

i have two variables that are assigned values from my database by a function

```
    let size: Size

    let ribbonTable: Ribbon
    
    async function findSizeCategory(): Promise<void> {
    const category = product?.category ;
    switch(category) {
        case "mens":
        size = await db.select().from(mens_size);
        break;
        case "womans":
        size = await db.select().from(womans_size);
        ribbonTable = await db.select().from(ribbon)
        break;
        case "kids":
        size = await db.select().from(kids_size);
        ribbonTable = await db.select().from(ribbon)
        break;
    }
    }
    await findSizeCategory()
```

but the typescript error occurs when i go to use them in the map function and if ribbonTable lengnth is greater than 0

```
        <label className="block">
            what size are you?
            <select>
            {size.map(s =>
                <option key={s.size_id} value={`${s.size_id}`}>{s.size}</option>
            )}
            </select>
        </label>

                {ribbonTable && ribbonTable.length > 0 && (
                    <label className="block ">
                        Select a ribbon:
                        <select>
                            {ribbonTable.map(r =>
                                <option key={r.ribbon_id} value={r.ribbon_id}>{r.ribbon}</option>
                            )}
                        </select>
                    </label>
                )}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your whole code so it may be a bit hard to tell, but from what I can see, you just need to assign initial values to the variables. Your `findSizeCategory()` function is `async`, and as such it's likely that the two variables will get initialized after the view is rendered.

So effectively, in the template, you are using these variables before they have a chance to be initialized which may result in an error.

In order to fix that, try setting a default value:

```
let size: Size = ...; // assign a default value matching the `Size` type
let ribbonTable: Ribbon = ...; // assign a default value matching the `Ribbon` type
```